# Jena does not see the classes of an OWL/RDF model

Tags: rdf, owl, jena

I developed an open Source tool based on Jena (3.15.0) which creates a diagram from the content on an OWL/RDF model. It usually works correctly, but I got from a colleague a model he works on on and on which Jena does not find any classes. I simplified the model as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:owl="https://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
  xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:my="MY:/">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://localhost/TEST">
    <rdfs:comment>Test ontology</rdfs:comment>
  </owl:Ontology>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost/TEST#My_Organisation"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Fact">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost/TEST#MY"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:ID="document">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost/TEST#MY"/>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

If I'm trying to open the model in Protégé (5.5.0), I see classes, but if I am using Jena with:

```
  URI uri = file.toURI();
  OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
  try {
     FileManager.get().readModel(model, uri.toString());
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After loading the model like that, I don't get any classes if I am doing (the iterator has no element):

```
ExtendedIterator classes = model.listClasses();
```

What's going on with this OWL/RDF model? Providing that with all my own OWL/RDF models, even complex ones, it saw the classes correctly. As I was not the one who created the OWL/RDF model, I must have forgotten something important which is responsible with this result. Does somebody sees what is wrong with the model (or the way I am parsing it in that case)?

Comment: your `owl:` namespace is wrong, it is **not** `https:` but `http:`- same for `xsd:` namespace. The URIs must be correct, the extact URI matters, there is no concept of redirects in RDF or OWL when identifying entities